# Mouse over element to reveal and click hidden element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium Webdriver in C# I need to mouse over an element which then reveals a menu of hidden elements, I then need to click an element that was previously hidden. I can't click the element which reveals the menu as this will redirect to another page.

Actions:

1. Hover over 'My Account' menu item to reveal hidden elements (Must not click this element)
2. Find and click the 'Update Details' element which was revealed as a result of step 1.

I'm using the following code, however; it raises the element not found exception for the 'Update Details' element.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement MegaMenu = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#tab-overview"));
action.MoveToElement(MegaMenu).Build().Perform();
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Update my details"))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only should need the Action to do the hover. Once you hover, you should be able to just click the element. I put a wait in there to make sure the page has a second to have the element be visible before you try to click it. You may not need it.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement MegaMenu = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#tab-overview"));
action.MoveToElement(MegaMenu).Build().Perform();
WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
IWebElement updateLink = Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("Update my details")));
updateLink.Click();
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't work as expected. I received an unable to locate element for the update details link. Is there another way to do this, for example using javascript?

Comment: @mpoulton you would need to provide the relevant HTML or a link to the page. I was just using the locator you provided in your code.